# Jquery .css returns undefined right after setting it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have the following code in my application. The first two lines paint an item in the table just fine. But when I just want to get the color of this item (which is "#FFFFFF") it returns undefined.
Those lines go in exactly that order, and there is nothing in between them.

```
var $item = $('#10.row').find('#3.col');
$item.attr('bgcolor', '#FFFFFF');
console.log($item.css('bgcolor'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `$item.attr('bgcolor', '#FFFFFF')` will make the HTML look like this:

```
<div id="10" class="row">
  <!-- bgcolor attribute added by JQuery: -->
  <div id="3" class="col" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"></div>
</div>
```

To set and get the CSS background color, use one of the following (both are valid in JQuery):

```
// Only use second parameter to set in both cases.
$item.css( "background-color", "#FFFFFF" ) 
// OR
$item.css( "backgroundColor", "#FFFFFF" )
```

Outputs like this:

```
<div id="3" class="col" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;"></div>
```

If you really want to add the HTML attribute `bgcolor`, you can fetch that attribute like this:

```
console.log($item.attr('bgcolor'));
```

So the final JS would look like this:

```
var $item = $('#10.row').find('#3.col');
$item.css('background-color', '#FFFFFF');
console.log($item.css('background-color'));
```

Or like this:

```
var $item = $('#10.row').find('#3.col');
$item.attr('bgcolor', '#FFFFFF');
console.log($item.attr('bgcolor'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the (deprecated) `bgcolor` attribute and then trying to access the CSS (non-existent) `bgcolor` CSS property which both doesn't exist, and isn't set.

As noted elsewhere, to set the `background-color` *set the `background-color`:

```
var $item = $('#10.row').find('#3.col');
$item.css('background-gcolor', '#FFFFFF');
console.log($item.css('background-color'));
```

The two are *not* interchangeable or equivalent, and `bgcolor` should no longer be used.